# Schengen calculations

Tags: schengen, us-citizens

I'm totally confused by the calculator and timid regarding purchasing my tickets. Would someone familiar with the system answer?

> recent stay:                       8/15/17 - 9/6/17   spain  23 days
>
> planning extended visit to portugal:     11/30/17 - 2/4/18  PT 67 days

Is this a legal stay? Both trips are just using my USA passport.

I have used three different online calculators and the official EU one is confusing on the terminology.

Comment: `is this a legal stay?` Why would you think otherwise ?

Comment: That would be exactly 90 days in the 180 day period from 8/15/17 to 2/11/18. It would be valid assuming you correctly counted your arrival and departure dates.

Comment: I would suggest cutting it a few days shorter. Any error or problem such as a missed flight could put you into an overstay.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan another option would be to plan to spend a few days in December or January in a non-Schengen country such as the UK, Ireland, or Morocco.